# Same background in multiple pages AEM

Tags: image, aem

I have this structure of pages with components inside

```
homepage
  - jcr:content
    - topBanner
      - background
        - file
secondpage
  - jcr:content
    - topBanner (different component from the homepage)
      - background (same component as homepage)
        - file
```

What I need is, when I upload an image to homepage background I want that same image goes to secondpage.

I have tried use granite properties but I'm stuck because I can't find AEM documentation for javascript

this is my serverside javascript for upload the image, based on image of AEM

```
"use strict";

use(["/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/AuthoringUtils.js",
"/apps/digital/components/content/utils/Image.js",
"/libs/sightly/js/3rd-party/q.js"], function(AuthoringUtils, Image, Q) {

var image = new Image(granite.resource);
var imageDefer = Q.defer();
image.resource=granite.resource;

var CONST = {
    PLACEHOLDER_SRC: "/etc/designs/default/0.gif"
};

// check if there's a local file image under the node
image.path=granite.resource.path;

granite.resource.resolve(granite.resource.path + "/file").then(function(localImageResource) {
    imageDefer.resolve(image);
}, function() {

    // Modifying the image object to set the placeholder if the content is missing
    if (!image.fileReference()) {
        image.src = CONST.PLACEHOLDER_SRC;
    }
    imageDefer.resolve(image);
});

// Adding the constants to the exposed API
image.CONST = CONST;

// check for image available sizes
if (image.width() <= 0) {
    image.width = "";
}

if (image.height() <= 0) {
    image.height = "";
}

return imageDefer.promise;
```

});

Basically I want to copy the file from homepage to secondpage and other pages that may exist. Or create a pointer in the background of the secondpage to the file from homepage.

How can I do this?

TopBanner Component HTML

```
<div class="dashboard-hello">

<div data-sly-resource="${ 'background' @ resourceType='digital/components/content/authored/vf_background'}"/>
    <div class="spring" id="homepage--greeting">
        <div class="dashboard-hello__content">
            <div data-sly-resource="${ 'greeting' @ resourceType='digital/components/content/authored/vf_greeting'}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `design_dialog` alongside the `dialog` of  the `background` component.

Design dialogs content changes are global accessible while dialog content changes are page specific. That means that the content stored via a design dialog is store at design path (usually somewhere under `/etc/design/`) while the content modified through the `dialog` gets stored at page level under component’s node.

You would have to modify the JSP rendering script of your `background` component also.

I would first obtain the background image path from the JCR property of the page specific content :`properties.get("<image_path_property_name>");`. If not set, I would fallback to the global background image `currentStyle.get("<image_path_property_name>");`. This way you would be able to set a different background image in `secondpage/../background` or "other pages that may exist".

Or if you don't want authors to use a different background image in the `secondpage/../background` pages, then only obtain background image path from the design property.

Comment: Yhnk you for your answer. But I'm new with AEM, and for what I have read to use design_dialog it is necessary to create dynamic templates, to be possible editing the background in design_dialog. My question is, how can I add a dinamic template inside html.
I have edited the post to add the html code of topbanner
I have tried with expirience frangments but this way I get all the pages with the same background